# Ubuntu 20.04 won't load, boot into initramfs

Tags: boot, 20.04, acer, initramfs

Hi I'm new in the Ubuntu world and i recently updated some drivers. After the reboot it wont load my System. If anyone can help!

[image]

Comment: There is little chance anyone can help given the level of detail you supply. "Some drivers"?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: while updating the software and bios a error acurred and it changed my boot into rsd something and changing it to htki something in bios it fixed it for me